# Keras model loss starts at 0, but only sometimes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to get a feel for what input parameters might work well for my data so I am training multiple models and trying to compare the results. For some reason some of the models start will a loss of 0 even when accuracy is very low. 
My code looks something like:
`first=keras.models.Sequential()
first.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation = 'tanh', input_shape = (X.shape[1], 1), return_sequences = True))
first.add(keras.layers.Dense(Y.shape[2], activation = 'softmax'))
first.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
models["first"]=first`

and I have a series of code blocks like that changing a few parameters in each one. 
Even before I try to fit the loss is already 0 (or 2.79e-7) for some of them, but not with any real consistency. Sometimes the first model will have that issue, sometimes the 3rd. I tried even just re-generating the data and the models when that happens, but when I do that the odds of the loss==0 issue seem to rise. 
The input data is in the form [[[5],[7],[3]...]...] and the labels were the same before I ran them though keras.utils.to_categorical and it is now 1 hot. I'm fairly certain the inputs and labels are correct as any given model works correctly most of the time.

Any suggestions would be useful at this point.

EDIT: This seems to only happen when running on the GPU. When I force TensorFolw to run only on the CPU there are no issues. Any idea what causes issues on the GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your random seed for reproducibility:

```
random.seed(10)
```

Also, if the model is stateless, the cell states are reset at each sequence. But if not for example if your using stateful = True, you will need to reset states after each training run.

Comment: How should I be setting the seed. I already set the seed for the data generation with numpy.random.seed(10) and tensorflow.set_random_seed(10) but how would I set the seed for keras?         Also any idea why a model would start with a loss of ~0 when accuracy is low?

Comment: numpy.randon.seed(10) should be sufficient. Two other thoughts, are you scaling your input data? Non-scaled input data can result in zero or NaN division in certain circumstances. see: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-scale-data-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/. 
Secondly,  Are you spliting your training/testing data the same way each time? I would test it on the same train/test split to see how consistent it is. May help narrow it down.

Comment: I tried scaling the input data to between 0 and 1, same problem. The training data and the testing data are generated separately from the same function but I just tried splitting it also with no change. The problem is happening before I even call fit as evaluate( with train or test data) already has a loss of 0